# Help with a PDE General Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have to find the general solution of the following:

$$x^2u_x+yu_y=1$$

in the quarter plane $x,y > 0$

I tried solving by simple ODE with an integrating factor of $x^{2y}.$

my general solution came to

$$u(x,y)=\frac{(x^{2y+1})}{(2y+1)}+f(y)$$.

My question is does my general solution make sense, also how does the "in the quarter plane $x,y>0$ affect my solution?

Also,

Find a solution which satisfies 
$$u(x,\frac{x}{2})=\frac{1}{x}+1$$.

Thanks!

Comment: $x^{2y}$ (as a real valued function) is only defined when $x\geq0$. Differentiability requires that $x >0$. Now in your solution (I haven't checked it) you divide by $2y+1$. Taking $y>0$ avoids the singularity at $y=-\frac{1}{2}$.

I suspect this is the reason for the $x,y>0$ requirement.

Comment: The equation isn't solvable at $x=y=0$, since it degenerates into the silly equation $0=1$ if $u,u_x$ are bounded at 0. Also if you relax to $x\ge 0, y>0$ you will see that you need $u|_{x=0} = \frac1{2y}$,

Comment: @CalvinKhor Although my solution uses $x>0$, using $x=0$ in it leads to $u=1/2y$.

Comment: @rafa11111 yes, I wanted to say, "consistent with rafa11111's answer" but was distracted. :)

Comment: Did you just change the pde with your edit? If so, you should probably mention it in the question, as the current answer will no longer be valid. You've completely changed the nature of the pde now ...

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The solution presented here was derived for the equation
$$x^2 u_x + y u = 1,$$
which was the original object of the question. This derivation *does not* work for the equation presented now in the question.

---

You probably made some mistake while solving the equation, because the formula for $u(x,y)$ you provided isn't a solution to the equation. However, you don't even need to use the integrating factor, since the equation is separable,
$$
\frac{u_x}{1-2yu}=\frac{1}{x}.
$$
You can now readily integrate both sides, but I usually do it in the following "fancy" way: see that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (1-2yu) = -2yu_x.
$$
Therefore, multiplying both sides of the separated equation by $-2y$ and changing $-2yu_x$ for $(1-2yu)_x$,
$$
\frac{(1-2yu)_x}{1-2yu}=-\frac{2y}{x}.
$$
Treating $y$ as a constant and integrating both sides (you can define $v=1-2yu$, and the LHS will be $v'/v$, whose integral is $\log |v|$),
$$
\log |1-2yu|=f(y)-2y\log |x|.
$$
Since $x>0$, $\log |x|= \log x$, therefore
$$
|1-2yu| = x^{-2y} \exp (f(y)).
$$
The RHS is always positive. Then, solving for $u$,
$$
u= \frac{1}{2y} + \frac{g(y)}{x^{2y}},
$$
in which $g(y) = \exp(f(y))/2y$. Just as Martin pointed out in his comment, the requirement of $x,y>0$ allows us to do such manipulations. If you needed the solution for $x<0$, for example, some steps would require modifications.

For the condition
$$
u(x,x/2) = 1+\frac{1}{x},
$$
we can simply substitute in the solution, leading to
$$
g(x/2) = x^x.
$$
Now, $g$ is simply a function, regardless of on which variable we are applying it; in the equality $g(x/2)=x^x$, $x$ is a *free variable*, because we can change $x$ for any other letter and the equality would be the same. Therefore, using $z=x/2$, we have $g(z)=(2z)^{2z}$, and the solution is
$$
u= \frac{1}{2y} + \left(\frac{2y}{x}\right)^{2y},
$$
which satisfy $u=1+1/x$ for $y=x/2$.

Comment: would you mind expanding a bit on the "fancy manipulation"? Also, I sincerely appreciate the time you spent correcting me.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify this part. Could you understand it now? See that it's only a method to integrate the LHS, if you already know the integral of $1/(a+bx)$, for example, or use any other method, you should obtain the same.

Comment: Yes that makes more sense to me now. Sometimes I have trouble with seeing how math is done if some steps are hidden. Thanks again!

Comment: Just a follow up to the original question. Finding a solution that satisfies u(x,x/2)=1+(1/x). I just plug that in and solve for the g(y), correct? My solution resulted in g(y)=x^x

Comment: @Mathl0rd1 Not quite... I will edit the question to address this "boundary condition". Could you, please, edit your question to add this condition, for the sake of "completeness"?

Comment: Did you check your solution $u= \frac{1}{2y} + \left(\frac{2y}{x}\right)^{2y},$ by putting it into the PDE $x^2u_x+yu_y=1$ ? It seems that it doesn't agree.

Comment: @JJacquelin I spent some minutes trying to show that the solution I found is right, until I realized it actually isn't indeed! However, if you compare the beginning of my answer to the [edits in the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3020310/revisions), you will see that OP changed the equation after I posted my solution. The original equation was $x^2 u_x +yu=1$. Time4Tea seems to have noticed that (check his comment in the question), but only now I saw it. How do you think I must proceed? Should I edit the answer to inform it doesn't correspond to the question or simply delete it?

Comment: I don't know what are the rules in such circonstance. I don't think that you should delate your answer since it is the answer to the previous question from the OP. May I suggest that you edit at the beginning of your answer : "This is the answer to the first version of the OP question with the equation : … , before the equation was modified."

Comment: @JJacquelin I edited the question, as you suggested. I will take a look in Meta about how to proceed with this situation. Thank you very much for pointing out the issue!

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2u_x+yu_y=1 \tag 1$$
Lagrange-Charpit equations :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{1}$$
A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y}$ :
$$\ln|y|+\frac{1}{x}=c_1$$
A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{du}{1}$ :
$$u+\frac{1}{x}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE $(1)$ is :
$$u+\frac{1}{x}=F\left(\ln|y|+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{x}+F\left(\ln|y|+\frac{1}{x}\right) \tag 2$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to boundary condition.

Condition : $u(x,\frac{x}{2})=\frac{1}{x}+1$
$$\frac{1}{x}+1=-\frac{1}{x}+F\left(\ln|\frac{x}{2}|+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$F\left(\ln|\frac{x}{2}|+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{2}{x}+1$$

Then finding $F$ involves a special function (Lambert W). This draw to think that there is a mistake in the condition specified by the OP.

If the condition is definitively $u(x,\frac{x}{2})=\frac{1}{x}+1$ the calculus is:

Let $X=\ln|\frac{x}{2}|+\frac{1}{x}$

$x=-\frac{1}{W\left(\frac12e^{-X} \right)}$

$W$ is the Lambert W function.
$$F(X)=-2W\left(\frac12 e^{-X} \right)+1$$

So, the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the general solution Eq.$(2)$ where $X=\ln|y|+\frac{1}{x}$
$$u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{x}-2W\left(\frac12 e^{-\ln|y|-\frac{1}{x}} \right)+1$$
$$u(x,y)=-\frac{1}{x}-2W\left(\frac{1}{2|y|} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} \right)+1$$